# Displaying arraylist just shows null values

Tags: java, arraylist

i have a small car dealership program here, everything seems to be working correctly (menus, adding cars and bikes to arraylist) except until it comes to choosing to display either the cars or bikes that  have added. The display method i have in the subclasses runs but it doesn't display any of the values i entered. It just shows something like: Model = null, price = 0.0, fueltype = null, etc.

I'm sure someone on here will be able to solve it in a matter of seconds!
If more code is needed just ask, i'm not sure where the error is so i just have the superclass Vehicles and the Driver input and display methods

Thanks

```
    public class Vehicles
    {
private final String make = "BMW";
private String model;
private double price;
private String colour;
private int stock;
private double fuelMpg;
private float displacement;
private int topSpeed;

public Vehicles()
{
    model = "";
    price = 0.0;
    colour = "";
    stock = 0;
    fuelMpg = 0;
    displacement = 0;
    topSpeed = 0;
}

public Vehicles(String model, double price, String colour, int stock, double fuelMpg, float displacement, int topSpeed)



    model = model;
    price = price;
    colour = colour;
    stock = stock;
    fuelMpg = fuelMpg;
    displacement = displacement;
    topSpeed = topSpeed;
}

public void display()
{
    System.out.println("Make: " + make);
    System.out.println("Model: " + model);
    System.out.println("Price: " + price);
    System.out.println("Colour: " + colour);
    System.out.println("fuelMpg: " + fuelMpg);
    System.out.println("displacement: " + displacement);
    System.out.println("topSpeed: " + topSpeed);
}



public void inputCarDetails()
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String model, colour, fuelType, frame;
    int doors, stock, topSpeed, stroke, noSeats, noVehicles, noCar;
    float displacement;
    double price, fuelMpg;
    boolean sunroof;
    Vehicles car;
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of cars you want to add to the brochure");
    noCar = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < noCar; i++) {
        System.out.println("----Entering car details----");
        System.out.println("\nEnter model");
        model = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Price");
        price = scan.nextDouble(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter colour");
        colour = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter no. in stock");
        stock = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter MPG");
        fuelMpg = scan.nextDouble(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter displacement");
        displacement = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter top speed");
        topSpeed = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter no. of doors");
        doors = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter fuel type");
        fuelType = scan.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Enter sunroof (true/false)");
        sunroof = scan.nextBoolean(); scan.nextLine();

        car = new Cars(model, price, colour, stock, fuelMpg, displacement, topSpeed, doors, fuelType, sunroof);
        list.add(car);
    }
}

public void inputBikeDetails()
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String model, colour, fuelType, frame;
    int doors, stock, displacement, topSpeed, stroke, noSeats, noVehicles, noBike;
    double price, fuelMpg;
    boolean sunroof;
    Vehicles bike;

    System.out.println("Enter the amount of bikes you want to add to the brochure");
    noBike = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < noBike; i++) {
        System.out.println("----Entering bike details----");
        System.out.println("\nEnter model");
        model = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Price");
        price = scan.nextDouble(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter colour");
        colour = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter no. in stock");
        stock = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter MPG");
        fuelMpg = scan.nextDouble(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter displacement");
        displacement = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter top speed");
        topSpeed = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter engine stroke");
        stroke = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter no. of seats");
        noSeats = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the frame type");
        frame = scan.nextLine();

        bike = new Bikes(model, price, colour, stock, fuelMpg, displacement, topSpeed, stroke, noSeats, frame);
        list.add(bike);

    }
}

public void displayCars()
{
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Unfortunatly, we have no cars on sale at the moment");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("\n****Car Brochure****");
        for (Vehicles v : list)
            if (v instanceof Cars) {
                v.display();
            }
    }
}

public void displayBikes()
{
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Unfortunatly, we have no motorbikes on sale at the moment");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("\n****Motorbike Brochure****");
        for (Vehicles v : list)
            if (v instanceof Bikes) {
                v.display();
            }
    }
} 

public static void main (String[] args) // main method
{
    BMWdriver driver = new BMWdriver();
    driver.Driver();
    driver.startMenu();
    driver.inputCarDetails();
    driver.inputBikeDetails();
}



    public class Cars extends Vehicles
    {
private int doors;
private String fuelType;
private final String layout = "RWD";
private boolean sunroof;

public Cars()
{
    super();
    doors = 0;
    fuelType = "";
    sunroof = false;
}

public Cars(String model, double price, String colour, int stock, double fuelMpg, float displacement, int topSpeed, int doors, String fuelType, boolean sunroof)
{
    super(model, price, colour, stock, fuelMpg, displacement, topSpeed);
    doors = doors;
    fuelType = fuelType;
    sunroof = sunroof;
}

public void display()
{
    super.display();
    System.out.println("No. of doors: " + doors);
    System.out.println("Fuel: " + fuelType);
    System.out.println("Wheel layout: " + layout);
    if (sunroof = false) {
        System.out.println("This car has no sunroof");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("This car has a sunroof");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us `Car` class ?

Comment: Where is this so called `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList <Vehicles> list = new ArrayList<Vehicles>();
```

you are missing this in your code. you have mentioned a list on sevral lines but there is no arraylist on the given code. declare this in your class and make it a instance variable

its really hard to give a correct answer by looking at the given details but if your class diagram is something very simmilar to this then your code is working

```
class Vehicle{
}
class Bike extends Vehicle{
}
class Car extends Vehicle{
}
```

and in your constructor you have to assign the values

```
this.model = model;
this.price = price;
this.colour = colour;
this.stock = stock;
this.fuelMpg = fuelMpg;
this.displacement = displacement;
this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
```

Comment: Apologies, I have that at the top of it, I just wasn't sure whether or not it was the root of the problem so I hadn't included it in the code I provided

Answer (score 0):

```
public Vehicles(String model, double price, String colour, int stock, double fuelMpg, float displacement, int topSpeed)



    model = model;
    price = price;
    colour = colour;
    stock = stock;
    fuelMpg = fuelMpg;
    displacement = displacement;
    topSpeed = topSpeed;
}
```

These assignments do nothing - you need :

```
this.model = model;
```

etc.